# ¿Qué es "una cana" en este caso?

Tags: traducción

[En este "Dilbert"](http://www.gocomics.com/espanol/dilbert-en-espanol/2011/09/24) pregunta un tipo, "¿esto es una cana?"

[image]

¿Qué quiere decir? "Cane" no tiene aquí sentido alguno...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una *cana* es un pelo de color cano, es decir, blanco:

> DRAE (23.a ed.)
>   **cano, na**
>   Del lat. *canus.*
>   **4.** *f.* Cabello que se ha vuelto blanco. *U. m. en pl.*

El estereotipo es que alguien con mucho estrés empieza a desarrollar pelo cano mientras todavía es de una edad más o menos joven.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando te estresas te salen canas, es decir, cuando tienes muchos nervios o estrés se suele decir que *te salen canas*. Es una frase hecha.